# How to change the default webcam in CEF Sharp?

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Computer has two webcams. How to tell to CEFsharp from which camera start recording? How to switch cameras via C# on the fly? My case is to chage default camera for Hangouts chatting in CEFsharp browser in WPF project.

I tried to search some info on CEF's forums but did not find any workaround there.

As a solution i tried switch off device fully (throught devcon.exe) but it require to reboot PC and it is unacceptable for me.

More over there is no notion of "Default" device for web-cams in Windows. This mean, that i cant change default camera on OS level.

So i want to change it on level of CEFsharp.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the important comment, I tried to edit my question so that it looked better.

Comment: You can change the webcam through JavaScript.

Comment: How? Can you provide some code snippet?

Comment: https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/